# Angular 1.6 $injector: unpr error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I got some data coming from an API and want to list it on a table.
**Angular 1.6**

I'm getting the error:

```
 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: nameFilterProvider <- nameFilter
```

This is my angular controller:

```
$app.controller('partnersAnalyticsController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$http',
    function ($rootScope, $scope, $http) {
      $scope.$on('yahoo_analytics_changed', function (e, args) {

        $http.get("https://api-metrics....", {
            headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ...'}})
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.testeYahoo = response.data.rows
           console.log(response.data)
        });
        $scope.groupType = args.data.period;
        $scope.currentPage = 1;
    });
});
```

This is my table:

```
    <tr dir-paginate="dado in testeYahoo | itemsPerPage: pageSize" current-page="currentPage" pagination-id="testeYahoo" style="cursor:default">
      <td>{{dado.dateTime}}</td>
      <td ng-if="groupType=='day'">x</td>
      <td>{{dado.app|name}}</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>{{dado.impressions}}</td>
      <td>$ {{dado.eCPM}}</td>
      <td>$ {{dado.revenueInUSD}}</td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div class="text-center">
    <dir-pagination-controls boundary-links="true" template-url="dirPagination.tpl.html" pagination-id="testeYahoo"></dir-pagination-controls>
  </div>
```

**EDIT**

This is array to show:

```
adNetwork|name: "Gemini"
app|name : "Estadão / Banner Horizontal"
clicks: 1085
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `<td>{{dado.app|name}}</td>` which means 'use the filter `name`'.

Check in your code if you are correctly registering this filter, it should be something like :

```
angular.module('myApp').filter('name', ['$filter', function($filter) {
     //some code for the filter
}])
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is the key of the array... `app|name: "Estadão / Banner Horizontal"` how can I show this without getting this error?

Comment: `app|name` shouln't be a filter...is just de key of the array that I recieved.

Comment: Then you have to wrap it, like ``dado["app|name"]``.